# Dice Game Expected Value

Tags: probability, expectation

You accumulate 1 point when rolling a 1,2, or 3. You get paid out your points when rolling a  4 or 5. You get nothing if you roll a 6. What is your expected value?

I came up with the following solution. I get 1 point with probability (1/6), 2 points with probability (1/12), 3 points with probability (1/24), and so on.

So then the EV is: $\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{2}^n \times (n+1)$

Two question: how do I actually evaluate that sum, and second how can I set up a recursive equation to solve the problem. It seemed like recursion would be easier but I couldn't set up the equation properly

Comment: There are many ways to evaluate the sum; try considering the general sum $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}nr^n$ for $|r|<1$. You could set up a recursion by conditioning on your first roll.

Comment: I don't understand the rules.  How many times do you roll?  What determines when you stop rolling?

Comment: The initial question would be interpreted as just one roll. So no infinite sum.

Comment: @quasi "You get paid out your points when rolling a 4 or 5" I interpret (based on perceived logic of OP's attempt and use of the word 'accumulate') to mean the game ends on these rolls and you win whatever you accumulated by previously rolling $1,2,$ or $3$. If you roll $1,2,3$ or $6,$ the game continues (but you only get a point for the first three).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: Here's a clarification. If you roll a 4,5,or 6 the game ends. If you roll a six you get nothing when the game ends. If you roll a 4 or 5 you get the points that you accumulated by rolling the 1,2,or 3 before. If you roll a 1,2, or 3 add a point to your total and roll again.

Comment: No, 6 is game is over and your point total is zero.

Comment: For example if I roll (1,1,1,4) my score is 3. If I roll (1,1,1,6) its zero

Comment: I don't think you can actually use recursion. Rolling a $1,2,3$ on roll one does not increase expectation by $1$.

Comment: But then presumably you have the option of stopping, so what strategy do you assume for that?

Comment: There is no strategy for this. The game functions by rolling until you are ended artificially, you have no choice whether to roll or not.

Comment: It's not zero. For example If I roll (1,1,1,4) I got a score of 3 with a nonzero probability, therefore the EV is already above zero

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Ah, I see. I expect you are right. Guessing at these rules is frustrating.

Comment: More than $\frac{1}{2}$ of the paths end in zero, because you can get zero by rolling a 4,5,or 6 on the first roll or by rolling a 1,2,3 then a six somewhere later on, so it has to be more than a half that lead to an outcome of zero. Just for reference my sum does give the correct answer of $\frac{2}{3}$, there is supposedly a nicer recursive solution to the problem which I am trying to figure out

Comment: Yes, there was a flaw in my argument.  I have deleted the incorrect comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the sum using the differentiation trick  $$ \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^{n} = \frac{1}{6}\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1} = \frac{1}{6} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$ Plugging in $x=1/2$ gives an answer of $2/3.$

As for recursion, this is trickier. The probability the game ends on a six is $1/3$ by symmetry since it is the probability you roll a six before you roll a four or five. So we may work in an imaginary world where sixes never occur. Let $V$ be the value of the game. We have a $3/5$ chance of landing on a one, two or three, in which case we gain one point and continuation. Otherwise, if we land on $4$ or $5,$ we gain nothing. The recursive equation is that $$V = \frac{3}{5}(\frac{2}{3}V+1)$$ (where the $2/3$ on the inner $V$ is to cut the continuation value to take into account the possibility of landing on a six) so that $V = 1,$ which we then multiply by $2/3$ to take into account the sixes, and get the answer of $2/3.$

Comment: My interpretation of the original question was that once you roll a $6$ you're out of the game and lose all the money you had accumulated up to that point.

Comment: Yeah, see my comment, that was my question sorry for the poor phrasing. The sum I gave does calculate the right EV

Comment: This makes sense. Perhaps the summation is the way to go here because this recursion was quite tricky

Comment: @GTOgod Yes, I like your original solution and am still trying to convince myself that what I wrote down makes sense.

Comment: I figured I'd add I found a slightly easier recursive method which conditions on the number of (1,2, or 3's) instead of the points. So one half of the time the game ends in 0 moves (4,5,6) and the other half of the time we are can recursively write the number of moves as n+1. So solving $n = \frac{1}{2} \times (n+1)$, we get $n = 1$. So the expected number of 1,2, or 3's rolled is one and we get paid on $\frac{2}{3}$ so then the EV comes out to the value we saw in the sum

Comment: @GTOgod Yes, that is easier to follow than mine. The expected number of points you have when the game ends is one, and then there's a $2/3$ probability that you get the points.

Answer (score 2):

If you have $$S=1 \times \frac16 + 2 \times \frac1{12} + 3 \times \frac1{24} + \cdots$$

then $$2S=1 \times \frac13 + 2 \times \frac1{6} + 3 \times \frac1{12} +4 \times \frac1{24} + \cdots$$

and so by subtraction $$S=2S-S= \frac13 +  \frac1{6} +  \frac1{12} +  \frac1{24} + \cdots$$

and if you do not know this then do the same thing again

$$2S=\frac23 +  \frac1{3} +  \frac1{6} +  \frac1{12} +  \frac1{24} + \cdots$$

so by subtraction $$S=2S-S = \frac23$$

Comment: This was very nice thanks

Comment: You can do similar things with other series, provided that all the series converge absolutely to a finite sum